# Can I leave after signing the offer letter?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, job-offer, hiring-process, software-development

I want to seek some advice I have 1 offer for the SDET role and I received an offer letter today HR is calling me again and again to make sure that I have confirmed and signed the offer letter because the tentative date of joining is 27 July and he needs to complete the process soon.

Recently I am interviewing for an SDE role until now 2 ( coding interview + discussion ) round has been done and they told me today that since it's Friday so they will let me know about the next step by Tuesday.

I am confused about what should I do. I reached out to some connections on LinkedIn and asked them for help, they advised me to accept and sign the offer letter and if I receive a offer letter from the second company( SDE role) then I should not join for SDET role even if I signed the offer letter. I just want to make sure that this will not lead to any problems and that I can deny to join freely.
Please help me I need urgent help on this one.

---

Notes:

SDET = Software Development Engineer in Test

SDE = Software Development Engineer

Comment: 1) Please punctuate your paragraphs into sentences. 2) What is SDET? SDE? Not everyone who reads this is familiar with your industry's abbreviations.

Comment: Where are you located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is somewhat unclear but it sounds like you have an offer for company A that wants you to sign write away but you prefer the job at company B, which is still in the interview process.

Once you sign with a company A, you have a legal contract. If you want to back out later, you either need to terminate the contract or just break it. The consequences of that depend a lot on your local labor laws and what the contract specifically says. In most US states there would be no legal or financial consequences but this varies a lot across the world.

In any case, it's not good for your reputation. You have made a promise and then you broke it. You will most likely never get a job at company A and if you run into the same people later, this may harm you.

Your best shot is probably to call company B and tell them that you have an offer on the table and if they could accelerate the process. At the same time, you can maybe stall company A for another day or 2.

If you can't, you just will have to make a decision. Sign on with company A and forget about B (for now), or decline company A and live with the risk that company B may not work out and you will have to keep on looking.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I will contact company B and ask them to accelerate the process and I will also ask company A if they can give me 1-2 days more to think and then accept/reject.

Answer (score 1):

*Can* you leave? Probably.

Will it lead to problems? Almost certainly - at best you can expect to get blacklisted by the company you spurned as unreliable. At worst, you could expect legal troubles for breach of contract; how likely that is depends on your jurisdiction.

It's a question of working out where your morals lie - are you someone who sticks to your word?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the legal position is in US.  But in my experience downunder, an offer letter is not a contract and is not binding on either side.  A prospective employer can change their mind if they like (and they have done so on many occasions for many people I know).  What is binding is the actual employment contract, which you sign later.

So accept the first one and wait for the second one.

Answer (score -1):

I have to disagree with Philip Kendall in some circumstances.  Here in the US we have some states that have a set of employment laws called "right to work".  While it sounds advantageous to workers, it is really for the benefit of employers.  Basically they can let you go anytime no reason given.  Also you can quit at any time.

If you are in a right work state, an offer letter is not a contract.  The company can withdraw the offer anytime and even let you go on the same day you show up for work.  "Turn around being fair play", you can withdraw from a signed offer and quit on the first day of work.

As the rules are written in such states it is not a moral obligation to fulfill an offer letter by either party.

In practice this doesn't happen much, especially in professional roles as there is a cost to recruiting.  However, it is possible.

The employment laws to your locale are key to understanding your obligation.

Comment: Are you confusing “at-will employment” and “Right to Work”?